# receives_twice(C, A): the client received exactly two transfers, each of which an amount not less than A;

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Relations are defined in the Prolog program

`account(B, C, N)`

- B is the name of the bank
- C is client
- N is the account number

`transactions(N1, N2, A, D)`

- N1 is the number of the sender's account
- N2 is the recipient's account number
- A is the transfer amount
- D is the date transfer

Write rule for the following relations:

a) `receives_twice(C, A)`
the client received exactly two transfers, each of which an amount not less than A;

```
account(reiffeisen, max, "0").
account(privat24, john, "1").
account(reiffeisen, olivia, "2").
account(privat24, jack, "3").
account(monobank, linda, "4").
account(monobank, omen, "5").
account(privat24, johnny, "6").
account(reiffeisen, historia, "7").
account(reiffeisen, clark, "8").
account(monobank, victor, "9").
transactions("0", "1", 100, "05").
transactions("1", "4", 200, "10").
transactions("1", "8", 500, "12").
transactions("9", "7", 100, "06").
transactions("5", "3", 5000, "08").
transactions("6", "9", 10, "01").
transactions("8", "7", 50, "02").
transactions("9", "0", 1200, "04").
transactions("5", "1", 800, "03").
transactions("3", "0", 1000, "07").
transactions("1", "6", 1400, "04").
transactions("6", "1", 2000, "05").
transactions("3", "1", 2500, "05").
transactions("1", "1", 2800, "05").

receives_twice(C, A) :-
    account(_, C, Q),
    transactions(_, Q, M, _),
    M >= A.
```

I don`t know how verify that the customer received exactly two transfers.

Comment: As a hint: `findall(..., ..., [E1, E2])`

Comment: the tasks must be performed without using the predicates maplist, forall, include, findall, bagof, setof and without involving the tools of the aggregate library;

Comment: "I don`t know how verify that the customer received exactly two transfers." - try finding two, try finding three. If two succeeds and three fails, they had exactly two. Although you'll have "fun" telling whether you're looking at the same transaction twice, or two separate transactions, when they don't have unique identifiers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can use a helper predicate:

```
call_goal_t(Goal, Goal, Bool) :-
    call(Goal), !,
    Bool = true.
call_goal_t(Goal, Goal, false).
```

The 2nd arg is then a convenient `transactions` *term*. And the 3rd arg is whether successful.

The rest of the code is:

```
receives_min(Client, MinAmount, Trans, Bool) :-
    % Allowing a client to have more than 1 account
    account(_B, Client, AccNum),
    receives_min_(AccNum, MinAmount, Trans, Bool).

receives_min_(AccNum, MinAmount, Trans, Bool) :-
    call_goal_t(transactions(_N1, AccNum, Amount, _D), Trans, Bool),
    (Bool == true -> Amount >= MinAmount ; true).

receives_twice(Client, MinAmount) :-
    receives_min(Client, MinAmount, Trans1, true),
    dif(Trans1, Trans2),
    receives_min(Client, MinAmount, Trans2, true),
    dif(Trans1, Trans3),
    dif(Trans2, Trans3),
    receives_min(Client, MinAmount, Trans3, false).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- receives_twice(C, 1000).
C = max ;
false.
```